# How to create subdomain for each store for a multivendor ecommerce website?

Tags: php, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Im working on a multivendor ecommerce website and I want to create subdomain for each new user.

My question is how do I create dynamic subdomains like http://storename.mywebsite.com ?

For the moment my website is working this way: http://mywebsite.com/storename

I get the value of store name this way:

```
$URL = explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$store = $URL[0];
```

I got stuck in what do add in my .htaccess and how to get the value of storename from the subdomain (storename.mywebsite.com)

Currenty my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

# directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

**N.B**

> I checked some answers here and I did use a wildcard and specified A records

*.mywebsite.com        IN         A       127.0.0.1 =>(Server IP Address)

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` gets you the host name of the request.

Comment: I know! That's why Im asking what do I need to do!

Comment: Well then what you need to do now, is ask a clear and precise question. I have no idea what exactly you are struggling with now.

Comment: My exact question is how to set subdomains to each store dynamically. Ex: storename.mywebsite.com

and how to retreive the current subdomain value from the current url storename.mywebsite.com so I can retrieve data from database to each store depending on the current url.

I hope you got my question.

Comment: Explode the value at the dot and take the first resulting element, or strip off `.mywebsite.com` from it ...

Comment: and how about the .htacces?
I think I need to add something like :
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$  index.php?storename=$1. 
right?

Comment: If you want to pass it as a parameter directly from your rewrite; my hints were more geared towards doing it directly in PHP. You will still have to fetch the info out of the host name then. RewriteRule matches against the URL _path_ only, so you will need to use a RewriteCond for that.

Comment: and How to change http://mywebsite.com/storename to http://storename.mywebsite.com with the htaccess?
I still didn't get the answer of this one!

Comment: Not an answer, but definitely a bad idea.  There are future repercussions for security certificates.  **Subdomain** is not a dynamic concept.  Also, webmasters is a better site to ask for htacess rules.  Mind you, my related question has had no answers there.  :-)

Comment: @RohitGupta 
So, since I'm creating a multivendor ecommerce platform in which users can create their own ecommerce landing page, is it possible to let users link http://mywebsite.com/userstore to their own domain name? if yes, can you give the idea how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it.  By users, do you mean vendors ?  They already have their own domains.  Surely, all you want is for them to have an unique link for each vendor such `mywebsite.com/stores/wallmart` and `mywebsite.com/stores/para_rubber`.  And they can place a link to it on their website.  And oyu should really start off with https, ie a security certificate.

Comment: Yes, I mean vendors. Im want to give them the posdibility to replace mywebsite. com/storename with their own domain name.

Comment: I know I will have to provide them with the severname (ei. dn1.servername.com and dn2 servername.com) something like that. but the problem that Im facing is how to achieve this step by step.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really kick off with a multi-domain security certificate and code for **HTTPS**.  It will be much harder later on.

From my experiments, you can do this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^storename1$ http://mywebsite.com/storename1?{QUERY_STRING}  [R=302,L]
```

But there are problems with this.

1. You need a separate certificate for every subdomain or one multi-domain certificate if you want to use HTTPS
2. You have to repeat this for every subdomain
3. It does a redirect so that the user actually sees the end URL (the URL with the subfolder is what the browser will show to the user)

If you want to avoid point 3, then the redirection has to happen higher up.  For instance, if your provider is using **cpanel** and you have access to it, then you can map each subdomain to a subfolder and the user will not see the subfolder in the URL path.

If you don't have access to such a tool, then ask your provider to map it for you.  Every time you add a new subdomain, you have to ask them to map it for you.